# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) SQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want that for an Update

```
UPDATE utilisateurs
SET NAME = 't',
SURNAME = 't',
LOGIN = 't',
PASSWORD = 't',
TYPE = 'Formateur',
M_ID = (SELECT M.M_ID, M.LABEL
        FROM matieres AS M
        WHERE M.LABEL = 'Culture_General')
WHERE U_ID = 3
```

But It's wrong and I don't know how

Comment: The sub-query should only return one column. not two. (And only one row.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
UPDATE utilisateurs
    SET NAME = 't',
        SURNAME = 't',
        LOGIN = 't',
        PASSWORD = 't',
        TYPE = 'Formateur',
        M_ID = (SELECT M.M_ID
                FROM matieres M
                WHERE M.LABEL = 'Culture_General'
               )
    WHERE U_ID = 3;
```

The subquery is a *scalar subquery*.  This should return exactly one column and at most 1 row.  This assumes that only one row is returned.  If you want to be sure, either use `LIMIT`:

```
        M_ID = (SELECT M.M_ID
                FROM matieres M
                WHERE M.LABEL = 'Culture_General'
                LIMIT 1
               )
```

Or aggregation:

```
        M_ID = (SELECT MAX(M.M_ID)
                FROM matieres  M
                WHERE M.LABEL = 'Culture_General'
               )
```